# La Basilica Palladiana

Tags: word-usage

***La Basilica  Palladiana*** (uno degli edifici storici più belli e famosi  d'Italia)

> - è un edificio pubblico che affaccia su Piazza dei Signori a Vicenza. Il suo nome è indissolubilmente legato all'architetto rinascimentale Andrea Palladio, che riprogettò il Palazzo della Ragione aggiungendo alla preesistente costruzione gotica le celebri logge in marmo bianco a serliane.
> - Un tempo sede delle magistrature pubbliche di Vicenza, oggi la Basilica Palladiana, dotata di tre spazi espositivi indipendenti, è teatro di mostre d'architettura e d'arte.
>   Dal 1994 è, con le altre architetture di Palladio a Vicenza, nella lista dei patrimoni dell'umanità dell'UNESCO. (Wikipedia)

[image]

La definizione di [basilica](http://www.focus.it/tecnologia/architettura/qual-e-la-differenza-tra-duomo-basilica-e-cattedrale) è:

> - letteralmente, la casa del re e cioè del Signore. Viene infatti dal greco basileus, che significa re, e da oikos, che vuol dire casa. Ogni chiesa, quindi, può essere considerata una basilica, ma la Chiesa attribuisce solo ad alcune di esse tale definizione: ciò avviene in funzione della loro importanza e valore artistico.

La basilica Palladiana non ha mai avuto negli ultimi secoli la funzione di una chiesa, anzi aveva la funzione di sede pubblica delle magistrature, perché quindi si chiama ***basilica***?

Comment: Forse citerei [una definizione più neutra di “basilica”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/basilica2/) (dove peraltro c'è già anche la risposta relativa a quella palladiana), che non sia inserita a priori nel contesto dell'edilizia cristiana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

È proprio il Palladio a coniare per l'edificio un nome coerente con le sue convinzioni: «Basilica», come nell'antica Roma veniva chiamato il luogo dove si gestivano la politica e gli affari più importanti.

«Basilica significa casa regale: e anco perché vi stanno i giudici a render ragione al popolo. Queste basiliche de’ nostri tempi sono in questo dall'antiche differenti, che l'antiche erano in terreno, o vogliam dire a piè piano, e queste nostre sono sopra i vòlti; ne’ quali poi si ordinano le botteghe per diverse arti, e mercatantie della città; e vi si fanno anco le pregioni» (Andrea Palladio, [I quattro libri dell'architettura](https://books.google.it/books?id=7ap84OP_BW8C&dq=Queste%20basiliche%20de%E2%80%99%20nostri%20tempi%20sono%20in%20questo%20dall'antiche%20differenti&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q&f=false), libro III, cap. 20).

[image]

Comment: Ci sono "[basiliche civili](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica)", come la Basilica Giulia e la Basilica Emilia nel Foro romano. Secondo me, non sono chiamate "impropriamente", è più probabile che la tua fonte parla sopratutto delle basiliche cristiane, non delle basiliche greche o romane.

Comment: Come fa giustamente notare @I.M., il senso originario di “basilica” precorre il cristianesimo: semmai, scherzando, potremmo dire che sono le chiese a essere chiamate “impropriamente” basiliche. In quelle romane si celebravano processi, si stringevano accordi commerciali o semplicemente si andava per incontrare qualcuno e magari giocare (sui gradini della Basilica Giulia a Roma si vedono ancora incisi tavolieri per giocare, di un parente del “filetto” e di altri giochi).